# LibGDX tools.jar missing

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, gradlew

One day ago I created a new LibGDX project.
All worked fine and I could also export the HTML files to test my project on a server.
I have used gradlew.bat

```
html:superDev
```

for debug and

```
gradlew html:dist
```

to export the project.
But today when I try to compile for html gradle says

```
Could not find tools.jar
```

[image: Error]

Comment: My guess is that you don't have Java Dev Kit, but only JRE. Is that right? Or, you don't have JAVA_HOME system variable.

Comment: I've both. But as soon as I restart Android Studio it fails compiling.

Comment: And you didn't change anything in build.gradle files recently, did you?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **tool.jar** is a library included in JDK (*Java Developement Kit*). The problem you have met is that you probably do not have JDK - just JRE (*Java Runtime Environment*). If you do have this then your Android Studio does not know where it is (and probably has set up the path to JRE).

In first case you can download and install JDK from [official Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

In second you need to go to the **Project Structure**

[image]

then provide proper JDK path:

[image]

Your IDE may need also restart after change.